# How to create stacked area chart with grouping

Tags: google-sheets

I have data that looks like below:

```
date city state covid
1/1  NYC  NY    10
1/2  NYC  NY    15
1/3  NYC  NY    12
1/4  NYC  NY    11
 .    .    .    .
 .    .    .    .
 .    .    .    .
 .    .    .    .
1/1  LA   CA    10
1/2  LA   CA    15
1/3  LA   CA    12
1/4  LA   CA    11
 .    .    .    .
 .    .    .    .
 .    .    .    .
```

and I want to create, in google sheet, a stacked area chart where the x-axis is date, the y-axis is a number of the covid case, and the chart is grouped by city. Is it possible to create such a chart with minimum extra tables created?

Answer (score 1):

You need one pivot chart that place the cities as the headers, for example, I added a column that combined the city and state, then used the following query to create the pivot chart that was used to create the chart in the example below.

```
=QUERY(A:E,"select A,sum(D) where D is not null group by A pivot E")
```

[image: COVID Cases]